# laravel verify emaIl error smtp 550. how to handle this error?

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

the user is registered and mail is sent to confirm the account

response code 250, but got code 550
invalid mailbox
and i have error 500 with web server[image: error laravel]

how to handle this error and show the user that his email does not exist?

part of my .env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.dmd120.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@dmd120.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@dmd120.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I understand that this is an smtp server error. And indeed this mailbox does not exist. How do I report this to the user (handle the error)? now, when performing this action, laravel issues error 500

Comment: So ... by default you're not supposed to paste images of your errors, but text. Next, you're trying to send email. Copy/paste part of your email config from your .env, IF you can answer the question if you're using IMAP or something similar. The error is "invalid mailbox", that's the actual error for your subject title

Comment: _"now, when performing this action, laravel issues error 500"_ - because you did not catch the exception this throws. _"How do I report this to the user (handle the error)?"_ - wrap the relevant part into try/catch, and properly handle the exception when it occurs then.

Comment: the thing is, I do not know where to apply try catch... I am registering a user and then sending a letter to him using the standard authserviseprovider method https://dpaste.org/yTcUR

Comment: @difficultphil don't post images, just copy past the error.

Comment: francisco
and what's on my screenshot, is something unclear? or can you just point and not be able to help? Well, that's what I understood. If you don 't know, keep quiet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tell you how to handle the error, I found the solution myself:

in app/Exceptions/Handler.php  add function

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof TransportException){
        return response()->view('errors.550',[],550);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e); 
}
```

add view resources/views/errors/550.blade.php with you text error and text to user

*and everyone is happy*